# R plot looks different in .pdf and ubuntu native graphics device

Tags: r, ubuntu, pdf, plot, rstudio

I am trying to draw a heatmap in Rstudios on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

However, when the plot is drawn and displayed using the native graphics output in Rstudio, it looks nice and alright as shown in the first plot. However, when I save it to a .pdf graphics, vertical white lines starts appearing and it looks really ugly like in the second plot.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to resolve it?

**Output from native R graphics in Ubuntu**
[image]

**Output from .pdf in Ubuntu**
[image]

Comment: It depends on how your pdf viewer renders the file (i.e, the view is different for different pdf-software). If you need to prevent that, the file needs to be saved as a png.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, exporting the pdf to png in inkscape resolves the issue.